# What are the white round holes at Antarctica and Arctica visible at pictures from Cryosat-2 satelite program?

Tags: satellite

At pictures from Cryosat-2 sometimes there is round hole(white circle) at the pole:

[image]
https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/c-missions/cryosat-2
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Difference-between-CryoSat-2-DEM-elevation-and-airborne-laser-altimeter-measurements-in_fig5_320632081

What is this exactly? If this is measurement problem please describe the reason the problem exists.

Comment: The satellite taking these images is in a Sun-synchronous orbit.

Comment: Cryosat-2: Satellite Orbit: Non sun-synchronous circular LEO orbit, mean altitude = 717 km, inclination = 92º, nodal regression of 0.25º per day. Ground track repeat cycle: 369 days (with 30 day pseudo subcycles). This configuration allows a sufficient coverage for the polar regions. https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/c-missions/cryosat-2

Comment: Maybe the software that is consuming the image doesn't have that part of the globe in its coordinate system definitions so it simply clips it out?

Comment: https://blogs.egu.eu/divisions/cr/2016/10/14/image-of-the-week-the-polar-hole/

Comment: There are many explanations possible for the gap, you can do wild guesses or you can also ask the person/team who created the image. Contact from the pdf: Correspondence to: Thomas Slater (py10ts@leeds.ac.uk)

Comment: The given email address is invalid, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Mapperz and lluke are correct in that this gap is due to CryoSat-2's orbit, which flies up to 88 degrees north and south from the equator and so doesn't acquire any measurements beyond it (hence the hole). This orbit was chosen to both maximise coverage of Arctic sea ice and to provide the high density of repeat measurements needed to measure changes in Antarctica and Greenland further away from the poles.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Thank You, for an answer,  What is the method to fill this measurement hole? Are there any other satelites that can scan this middle region? I am not into satelites and I am wondering if the angle of scanning camera can be adjusted to shot sideway to cover this area even with the cost of worse terrain mapping.